# Python code with multiprocessing is slower with 32 cores than 16 cores on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing

I don’t understand why time of my calculation’s is longer while I using 28-30 cores than when I use 12-16 cores on AWS EC2 c3.8xlarge. I did some test and result are in chart below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u32jttxmkvnacd/Slika%20zaslona%202015-01-11%20u%2018.33.20.png?dl=0

The fastest computation is when I use 13 cores. So if i use maximal cores, it is same time as i am using 8 cores of c3.8xlarge:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gf3bevbi8dwk5vh/Slika%20zaslona%202015-01-11%20u%2018.32.53.png?dl=0

This is simplified code of code that i use.

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as th
import numpy as np

x=mp.Value('f',0)
y=mp.Value('f',0)
arr=[]
tasks=[]
nesto=[]

def calculation2(some_array):
    global x, y, arr
    p=False
    a = np.sum(some_array)*random.random()
    b = a **(random.random())
    if a > x.value:
        x.value=a
        y.value=b
        arr=some_array
        p=True
    if p:
        return x.value, y.value, arr

def calculation1(number_of_pool):
    global tasks
    pool=mp.Pool(number_of_pool)
    for i in range(1,500):
        some_array=np.random.randint(100, size=(1, 4))
        tasks+=[pool.apply_async(calculation2,args=(some_array,))]

def exec_activator():
    global x, y, arr
    while tasks_gen.is_alive() or len(tasks)>0:
        try:
            task=tasks.pop(0)
            x.value, y.value, arr = task.get()
        except:
            pass

def results(task_act):
    while task_act.is_alive():
        pass
    else:
        print x.value
        print y.value
        print arr

tasks_gen=th.Thread(target=calculation1,args=(4,))
task_act=th.Thread(target=exec_activator)
result_print=th.Thread(target=results,args=(task_act,))

tasks_gen.start()
task_act.start()
result_print.start()
```

It’s core are 2 calculation’s:

- calculation 1 - computing array and making jobs for calculation 2
  with that array
- calculation 2 - computing some calculation’s out of array and compare of results

The goal of code is to find array that compute maximum x, and return its y.
The two calculations start simultaneously (with threading) because sometimes there are too many array’s that take up too much RAM.

My goal is to do the fastest computation. I need advice how to use all cores if possible.

Sorry in advance if bad english. If you need more information be please to ask.

Comment: With too many cores compared to RAM available, you may be using virtual memory (swapping to/from disk, to simplify) which can easily slow you down.  Only general solution is to get more RAM.  Depending on the details of your task, actually working from disk in a proper sequential way can be faster than sucking it all into "memory" that can be virtual.  Alternatively, if you can use local SSD as your "disk", that can offer much-faster random access (I don't know how to do that in AWS, only on the Google Cloud Platform).

Comment: I'm using psutil to supervise processors and RAM. On tested data it used max 2-3% of RAM. I transfer all data and python code on Ubuntu server (EBS).

Comment: Interesting topic. How do you test it, I run the it on a micro instance, and get result less in 0.2s `[[86 44 89 88]] \n real 0m0.175s`

Comment: The code up is simplified code and its very fast on any computer, I put it just to show how I structured the real code. Here I just put some random array to calculate some random data. The real code is 3-4x longer and more complex and it's depend on intraday stock data from my hard disk. Def and variables are written on my native language so I must change a lot to show it here.

Comment: According to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ you have 32 *hyperthreads*, not physical cores.

Answer (score 5):

The c3.8xlarge is an Ivy Bridge quad core system. It uses Hyper-Threading; it doesn't really have 32 (hardware)independent processing units.

There's often no point in trying to parallelism a CPU bound task across more OS processes than what their are processors in the hardware. In fact, quite often it's detrimental due to the resource overhead and context switching (which is what you're seeing).

It likely depends on your specific applications, and experimentation will help you find the sweet spot (which it sounds like you've done).